# Определить математически <<средний цвет>> из 2х

Tags: c#, цвета

Имеем 2 цвета, заданы в RGB, по 1 байту на цвет.

Если брать и складывать каждый из цветов, затем делить на 2, то получается на мой взгляд не совсем верно. Допустим FF0000 и 00FF00 таким образом родят 7F7F00, который смотрится намного темнее, чем оба его "родителя". Если таким образом считать средний между FF0000 и FFFF00, то будет FF7F00, который на взгляд явно ближе к FF0000, чем к FFFF00. На взгляд средний между ними примерно FFAA00.

В каждом пикселе монитора мы имеем 3 субпикселя, питание подаваемое на которые изменяется от 0 до 255 (некоторых баллов) при данной глубине цвета, если я всё верно понимаю. Хочу узнать, как можно математически просчитать цвет, который был бы "средним" между двумя заданными, а именно был бы похож на каждый из них в равной мере, при этом имея среднюю между ними яркость.
Возможно, есть стандартные библиотеки в средах разработки, которые делают что-то подобное?

```css
div {
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-indent: -12ch;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:after {
  content: attr(style);
}
```

```html
<div style=background:#FF0000></div>
<div style=background:#7F7F00></div>
<div style=background:#00FF00></div>
<br><br>
<div style=background:#FF0000></div>
<div style=background:#FF7F00></div>
<div style=background:#FFFF00></div>
```

Comment: А что такое «математически средний цвет»? В зависимости от определения разный код будет правильным. Как по цвету определить яркость и то, насколько он _похож_ на другой цвет?

Comment: @VladD если бы я знал алгоритм, то не задал бы такой вопрос. Итоговый цвет должен быть на взгляд примерно одинаково быть похожим на родителей, а не на одного больше, чем на другого, но при этом быть настолько же ярким, как и они (или не ярким, если они типа 005555). Например, если смотреть оттенки зелёного, то они очень сильно похожи друг на друга (или у меня такое зрение). Математически значит, то нужен некоторый алгоритм решения, а не таблица для сопоставления.

Comment: Попробуйте брать средние не по RGB, а по HSL, или даже HSLuv.

Comment: Ну, вы выкатываете новый, никому не знакомый термин («математически средний цвет») без определения, и спрашиваете, как его правильно подсчитать. Без строгого определения нам придётся гадать, что вы имели в виду.

Comment: @VladD >>Как по цвету определить яркость и то, насколько он похож на другой цвет? -- сравните FFAA00 и FF7F00 с FF0000 и FFFF00 глазами, явно FF7F00 слишком близок к FF0000, а вот FFAA00 похож на требуемый ответ. Имелось ввиду "определить математически" и "средний цвет", слово "математически" зависимо от "определить", а не от "цвет".

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин: «Глазами» — это субъективный критерий. Мне кажется так, вам по-другому. И как личные впечатления оформить в виде числа?

Comment: Просто "средний" это понятие скорее из математики и результат прямо зависит от используемой цветовой модели. Какая вам кажется подходящей, знаете только вы.

Comment: @D-side: Я бы сказал, психофизиологической модели (если такая существует). Цветовая модель — штука скорее техническая.

Comment: @VladD идеальный результат ТСа да, но его ведь интересует техпроцесс. А их много.

Comment: @VladD это и есть суть вопроса. Для получения точных цифр, я так понимаю, что нужно разобраться как именно вычислительная машина управляет питанием субпикселей монитора. Если вам кажется, что FF7F00 больше похож на родителей, чем FFAA00, то у меня что-то со зрением. Видимо, вопрос поставлен не точно. Кол-во суммарно подаваемого питания на 3 субпикселя монитора должно быть средним от 2х родителей, пропорции каждого цвета должны быть так же средними. Но судя по моему восприятию, шкала 0-255 не является линейнозависимой от питания, поэтому простое деление на 2 даёт совсем не тот ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В RGB нельзя высчитать "средний" цвет. Во первых, яркость разных цветов воспринимается глазом по разному - т.е. яркость не "определяется наибольшим значением любого из 3 цветов".

В RGB ([sRGB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB)) зеленый ярче красного, красный ярче синего. FF0000 по яркости совпадает с 009B00 (справа), а не с вырвиглазным 00FF00 (слева):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во вторых, отсчет яркости не привязан строго к 0, и простое "уполовинивание" значения дает слишком темные цвета. Например, "полуяркий красный" - это, скорее, A60000, а не 7F0000, как можно было бы ожидать.

Для правильного смешивания цветов их стоит предварительно перевести в цветовое пространство, отражающее человеческое восприятие, например, [Lab color space](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAB), и высчитывать среднее уже в этом пространстве. Вот сравнительные результаты для чистых R G и B (сверху - с преобразованием в Lab и усреднением, снизу - с усреднением в RBG).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что усреднение по RGB дает слишком темный результат, а усреднение через Lab - средний по яркости.

В C# реализуется достаточно легко, готовые форумы есть по ссылкам на вики выше. Если не хочется вручную вписывать преобразование - [возьмите готовую библиотеку](https://github.com/THEjoezack/ColorMine):

```
PM> Install-Package ColorMine
```

```
var color1 = new Rgb() { R = 255 };
var color1Lab = color1.To<Lab>();

var color2 = new Rgb() { G = 255 };
var color2Lab = color2.To<Lab>();

var averageLab = new Lab()
{
    L = (color1Lab.L + color2Lab.L) / 2,
    A = (color1Lab.A + color2Lab.A) / 2,
    B = (color1Lab.B + color2Lab.B) / 2,
};

var averageLabRgb = averageLab.ToRgb();
```

Comment: @codename0082016 а у вас - что-то то не так со способностью писать конструктивные комментарии

Answer (score 3):

Есть две модели смешивания: адитивное и субтрактивное смешение цветов. Можно почитать тут https://creativshik.com/pochemu-vret-monitor/

Адитивное будет так (оно "работает" при световом смешивании лучей, в некоторых графических программах):

```
r =  (r1 + r2 ) / 2;
g =  (b1 + b2 ) / 2;
b =  (b1 + b2 ) / 2;
```

Cубтрактивное

```
r =  // TODO:
g =  
b =
```

Второе "смешивание" цветов похоже на привычное смешивание "акварельных красок" на белом листе. Ещё такое смешивание можно включить в Corel Draw.

Адитивное - "приближает" цвета к чёрному. А субтрактивное - к белому.

Если стоит задача определить "ближайший" цвет,
 то используется сумма rgb c коефициентами

```
Q = r * Kr + g* Kg +  b*Kb;
```

Где Q- будет "вес" по которому можно определить схожесть. этой формулой переводят изображение в чёрнобелое. Для разных преобразований используют разные коефициенты. Стандартные для ч/б где-то видел - найду запишу.

---

Коефициенты нашёл, вот

> Y=0.299*R+0.587*G+0.114*B (В.Порев "Компьютерная графика", BHV, 2002г. -
>   страница 41.)
>
> Y= 0.2125R + 0.7154G + 0,0721В (Фотошоп [ссылка](http://www.hardforum.ru/t49119/) )

При попытке вставить коефициенты - они в формуле сокращаются, т.е. для Y(R=255,G=0,B=0)=76,5 , Y(R=0;G=255;B=0)=150,45. Средний цвет будет (128,128,0), но и средняя яркость будет тоже средней - 113,48. Если вы хотите "поднять" яркость до max(Y(цвет1),Y(цвет2)) то вы можете пересчитать цвет, учитывая формулу приведённую выше.

Если у вас задача "не потерять яркость", тогда ставим задачу - сохранить максимальную яркость.

```
 Y(Red=255) = 76,5   Y(Green=255) = 150,45,  Y=(Red+Green) = 113,48;
 t = Ymax / Y =  150,45/113,48 = 1,325 
 Тогда (адитивное смешение):
 r` = (r1 + r2)*t/2  = (255 + 0)*1,325/2 = 170
 g` = (g1 + g2)*t/2  = (0 + 255)*1,325/2 = 170
 b` = (b1 + b2)*t/2  = (0 + 0)*1,325 / 2 = 0
 Y(R=170,G=170,B=0) = 150,45
```

Для субтрактивного смешения можно написать аналогичную формулу. Можно так же в цикле прибавлять еденицу - выйдет похожее значение (R=169,G=127,B=42). Внизу пример, сначала R (255,0,0), потом результат "затемнённый" R+G (128,128,0), Потом скорректированый по яркости (170,170,0), потом сделаный инкрементом (169,127,42). Потом зеленый (0,255,0)
[image: Сложение]

И последнее, ставьте проверки что б компонента не выходила за пределы [0,255], если меньше 0 то присваивать 0, если более 255 то ставить 255.

Comment: Мне кажется, в этом вопросе не стоит использовать rgb. С ней вряд ли что-то правдоподобное получится.

Comment: Так и есть, Вы правы насчёт моделей. Но дело в том, что я описал выше. Судя по восприятию, этот вычисленный цвет не является средним на самом деле. Значит, либо глаза врут, либо шкала 0-255 не является линейнозависимой от настоящего подаваемого питания на субпиксель. А гугл ну ни в какую не хочет рассказать, как именно, например, добавление +1 к числу цвета (0-255) повлияет на реальное питание на субпиксель монитора.

Comment: этими двумя моделями пользуется половина мира. Если вы хотите сделать цвет светлее - то используя третью формулу, вы можете поднять три компоненты до нужного уровня светлости, который зависит от коефициентов. Если хотите построить свою модель - пробуйте. Но скорее всего вернётесь к этой.